# Replacing modem with a vpn router

Tags: vpn, router, pptp, modem

Can I replace an open network iconnect 624 modem with a cisco router in a small network that needs multiple PPTP VPN connection? iconnect 624 modem doesnt allow multple simultaneous PPTP VPN channels? So if i replace this modem with a cisco 881 router, will it work for ADSL 2+ internet and multiple simultaneous VPN connection? Please advice. Thank You.

Comment: Inbound VPN, or outbound VPN?

Comment: This modem should work as a medium for outbound VPN to head office.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cisco 800-series routers are very flexible devices, but they do not have built-in ADSL modems, so you will need to provide a modem device to put on the WAN link.

You should do fine with one. We have a few of them and we have many outbound PPTP VPNs running through them.

Comment: Could i please have the model name of any modem router which allows multiple simultaneous VPN channels?

Comment: @ryju - we don't do shopping recommendations on any of the [se] sites because of their very limited lifespan. See [Q and A is hard, lets go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping) and the [FAQ] for more details. However adding a simple ADSL2+ modem onto the WAN link of an 881 is cheap and easy.